# ASP.NET WEB API and MVC routing - The requested resource does not support http method 'GET'

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-mvc-routing

In my `RouteConfig` I have the following code:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

In my WebApiConfig:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

    GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters
                                     .JsonFormatter
                                     .MediaTypeMappings
                                     .Add(new RequestHeaderMapping("Accept", "text/html", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase, true, "application/json"));

    config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
}
```

And in my Global.asax:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
    GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
    FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
    AutoMapperConfig.Start();
}
```

As I gathered from other topics on this subject matter, mvc routing must come last, which is the case here.

When I start my application, I get the following error:

"The requested resource does not support http method 'GET'."

I wonder if it has something to do with `config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();` in the API routing config file?

And yes, I have a HomeController with an Index action method:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";

        return View();
    }
}
```

What I also tried is putting a `HttpGet` attribute like so:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";

        return View();
    }
}
```

Something somewhere is doing something, and I like to know what.

Thanks!

EDIT:

One of my Api controllers:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/v1/gebouwen/{gebouwId}/meldingen")]
public class MeldingController : BaseController
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("", Name = "GetMeldingen")]
    public IHttpActionResult Meldingen(string gebouwId)
    {
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("{meldingId}", Name = "GetMelding")]
    public IHttpActionResult Melding(string meldingId)
    {
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [Route("", Name = "PostMelding")]
    public IHttpActionResult Melding(MeldingModel meldingModel)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Please can you confirm that it is the WebApi method that you are receiving this error message on?  If so, can you show us the signature of your WebApi Method as the one you've posted is an MVC controller (Inherits from Controller and not ApiController).

Comment: I guess this is what I'm also trying to figure out; what is it doing and where is it going? My assumption for now is that the page it is loading on start up is going to the Index action method on the HomeController (MVC).

The thing is that I have routing attributes on all my action methods on the API side. Hence the line `config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();` in `WebApiConfig`. I wouldn't know what to show you :-)

Comment: We need to see that Api Controller really I think to confirm that it is correct.

Comment: I want to comply, but I have several Api controllers. Should I just show you one of them?

Comment: Show the one that you are trying to navigate to and the URL that you are trying to navigate to, the path.

Comment: Ah, I get it! You think I'm trying to navigate to a particular Api controller, but this is not the case! I created a Web Api 2 project with asp.net MVC (for the help page). I'm not trying to go anywhere; I start up the application and expect to see a home page, which I assume to be asp.net MVC, hence me blabbing on about HomeController and the Index action method.

Comment: @AyatollahOfRockNRolla, The routes are conflicting. Web api is registered before MVC. And if you do not have a different route configured for the Web API then it will match Web API before MVC. Show what ApiController looks like.

Comment: Alright, I put up one of my Api controllers.

Comment: How are you navigating to one of your controllers, generally the route to an API controller would be `/Api/Controller/Id` are your registrations distiguished from your MVC controllers in some way?

Comment: Yeah, so, what I did for the Api part of the project is use RoutingAttributes. To test things with the Api I just type wherever I want to go into the url bar. E.g., localhost:57384/api/v1/gebouw/8f0e0a42-5116-40cf-bf54-7b1b1a992f15/meldingen would give me a list of meldingen. I guess they are different in the way that Api routing is configured like I just said, and the MVC part of the application has the traditional {controller}/{action}/{id} thing going on.

Comment: I just figured out that if I remove `GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);` from `Application_Start()` it works as expected. So there must be something getting in each others' way

Comment: I got it working! Instead of Api routes first and Mvc routes last, I switched the order and now it works. Unbelievable! I want to thank you for your tenacity @Luke Also: and now you know :-D